# My checklistbox doesn't display my array in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, checklistbox

I'm writing a program to be used by my library as a step by step checklist when adding new materials (books) to the collection.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Public Class frmCircCounter

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection

    'confirms all boxes have been checked, and clears them
    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        'If

        '    End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckedListBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox4.SelectedIndexChanged

        'I'm not sure what this is for the internet told me to add this?
        InitializeComponent()

        'establishes the arrary displayed in the checklistbox
        Dim strProperPackage() As String = {"Call Number and Authors Last name?", "Sub-Category Sticker?", "Plastic Wrapping on the Cover if needed?"}

        'displays it... or it should!!!?
        clbProperPackage.Items.AddRange(strProperPackage)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I expect to have the array displayed in the CLB upon execution

Comment: `InitializeComponent()` should only be called in the form's constructor.

Comment: Do you really want to populate that `CheckedListBox` every time the user selects an item in a different `CheckedListBox`?  I'd wager not.  It's pretty much certain that that code is never even being executed.  Put a breakpoint on that line using the F9 key and see if it ever gets hit.

Comment: Most likely you should get rid of all that code and create an handler for the `Load` event of the form, then populate the `CheckedListBox` there.  That will be executed just before the form is first displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your array and add each item into it.

```
For Each item As String In strProperPackage
  clbProperPackage.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: That's not going to help.  `AddRange` is the correct way to add multiple items.  The issue here is that the code is never being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your script will not execute the correct way because your using selected index changed but this will only run when a item has been selected in the list.

The best way to test this is by creating a new button and assigning this code to that button. With the button, the script will execute on click.

Public sub btnAccept (sender as object, e and eventargs) handles btnAccept.click

Dim strProperPackage() As String = {"Call Number and Authors Last name?", "Sub-Category Sticker?", "Plastic Wrapping on the Cover if needed?"}

'displays it... or it should!!!? clbProperPackage.Items.AddRange(strProperPackage)

End Sub